# Adempiere workflow process throw llegalStateException

Tags: adempiere

I implemented a workflow and workflow process for a custom table in adempiere 3.80. 
But when I click on the docaction button a popup will appear and when I click on its OK button, a message box appeared as terminated.
In eclipse, the console shows an exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Persistent Object not DocAction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your custom table has the model classes generated and that your MCustomTable class implements the DocAction interface.

Here is the MOrder model

```
public class MOrder extends X_C_Order implements DocAction
{
....
```